# Liferay how to compare 2 versions of a web content (Highlight differences for example)

Tags: workflow, compare, liferay, webcontent

I am using Liferay 6.1.1 and tomcat 7.
I am looking for a way to compare 2 versions of a web content.
Let say a user edits a web content and submit it for publication.
The content reviewer may want to know what exactly have been changed before he approves (or rejects) the newly submitted content.
Does someone can help me to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

The JournalArticleLocalServiceUtil is your friend. You can get the content from an article like this:

```
final JournalArticleDisplay articleDisplay = JournalContentUtil.getDisplay(groupId,     
                                                  article.getArticleId(),
                                                  article.getTemplateId(), 
                                                  languageKey, 
                                                  themeDisplay);

String content = articleDisplay.getContent();
```

The other parameters tou'll have to fetch from the ThemeDisplay.

Good luck